# Centering a tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am using beamer and including many tikzpictures. If my picture is not too large, it is centered, but if it is a bit too large, then it does not work anymore.

The following frame

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a sample}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[hide x axis,hide y axis,x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm]
        \addplot[patch,patch type=rectangle,color=blue,faceted color=white]
        coordinates {(-1.3,-1.1) (-1.3,1.1) (1.3,1.1) (1.3,-1.1)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

yields

[image]

but

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a sample}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[hide x axis,hide y axis,x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm]
        \addplot[patch,patch type=rectangle,color=blue,faceted color=white]
        coordinates {(-2.3,-1.1) (-2.3,1.1) (2.3,1.1) (2.3,-1.1)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

yields

[image]

How can I make to have something centered but large? (the whole screen would be perfect, but scaled to have squares which are squares).

Comment: `\leavevmode\hidewidth\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\hidewidth\null`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. I do not understand at all what this sentence means (I use LaTeX for a long time but am far from being an expert), but it works! I do not know well how Tex.SE works but if you want to make an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @RomainPicot Thanks. As you have seen, I am new here (even if it is not so true: I tried to ask many questions but until now each question was already answered on this nice forum...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.